# Dictionary lookup KeyError when no objects found

Tags: keyerror

I'm reading in two files to get a list of Organisations and a list of Products that need to be in the output file.

There's then a list of orders.  I only need to get the orders that relate to the Organisations and Products; the others can be ignored.  The orders have an OrgID so I'm using a lookup function on a dictionary created from Organisations to get the CustomerName, which is required for the output.

Here's the code

```
#read the input file
df1 = pd.read_csv("BillingFile.csv")

#assign OrgID values from the input companies list
df2['OrgID'] = companies

#get the Customer & Domain Name values
key_list = list(df2['OrgID'])
dict_lookup = dict(zip(df1['id'], df1['customer_name']))
df2['CustomerName'] = [dict_lookup[item] for item in key_list]
```

This code works perfectly if there is an order for every Organisation. However, if there is an Organisation from the companies input file that does not have any orders then I get an exception thrown 'KeyError' on the last line of code because the Organisation does not exist in the lookup.

Is there a way to alter the code to ignore the fact that nothing was returned for the key? Or should I refactor the code in another way to handle this?

Thanks